# Why did Sri Krishna say he was VAJRA among weapons?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, krishna, bhagavad-gita, indra

While giving discourse to Arjuna, Sri Krishna says that he was VAJRA among weapons.

> आयुधानामहं वज्रं धेनूनामस्मि कामधुक्।
>
> प्रजनश्चास्मि कन्दर्पः सर्पाणामस्मि वासुकिः।।10.28।।
>
> Of the weapons,I am the Vajra [of Indra]; of the cows, I am the Wish-fullfilling Cow [of the heaven]; of the progenitors, I am Kandarpa (the god-of-love); of the serpents, I am Vasuki.

In the Chapter 10 of Bhagavad Gita, Sri Krishna compares himself with the greatest among various living/non-living beings, viz., among Adityas - vishnu;; among birds - Garuda, etc.

We have to remember that in Vedas, Indra was described to have eliminated Vritra with Vajra.

Now the question is - why did  he not mention about Sudarsana Chakra, the weapon of  Vishnu (or) Trishula of Shiva, which are considered to be SUPREME in Puranas, but mentioned about VAJRA, the weapon of Indra?

Comment: Maybe it is because He does not think of Sudarshana Chakra as a weapon. Because I think in some places Sudarshana Chakra is said to be a living being which incarnates along with Lord Vishnu in some of His avatars, like Garuda or Adisesha :).

Comment: @Sai: What about Trishula of Shiva? It was also described to be SUPREME, in Puranas.

Comment: I am not sure, but my guess is this: the Trishula by itself is a very powerful weapon, but it is not most powerful. However because Lord Shiva wields it, it becomes Supreme. So when Sri Krishna refers to the supreme weapon (not the supreme wielder of weapons) he refers to the Vajra, which is a very potent weapon. However if you were to say that the Trishula is held by Lord Shiva, then it becomes infintely powerful, by virtue of the One who is holding it in the hand,. THanks

Comment: Vajra - is considered as the strongest material in the world.

Comment: I feel at that time atomic weapons were not available. Whatever was best during then could have been said. For example, today Hydrogen/Nuclear bombs are the most destructive. Now some people may compare them with *Brahmastra*, but nobody can be sure.\

Comment: @iammilind The notion that the Brahmastra is a nuclear bomb is based on the misconception that when a Brahmastra strikes some place, there won't be rain for twelve years.  But actually what the Mahabharata states that when one Brahmashirastra is blocked by another one, there won't be rain in that place for twelve years.  If the Brahmastra really was a bomb, then there would be devastating effects on the place regardless.  The fact that only collision with another Brahmastra matters is all the more evidence that the Brahmastra is a magical arrow, not a bomb.

Comment: @iammilind: The usage of Brahmastra in a subtle way was different from Ramayana era and Mahabharata era. The warriors of Mahabharata era like Drona, Arjuna, etc, knew about it for mass destruction only.  It is not in the case of warriors of Ramayana era.  Sri Rama used it against a crow, the son of Indra (narrated in Sundara Kanda).  That Astra chased him all the worlds and finally at the wish of Sri Rama it removed one eye only.  Indrajit used it for mass destruction as well as for arresting Sri Hanuma.  Thus the astra can be used at the wish of the user also.

Comment: VAJRA is certainly not as powerful as the Sudarshan Chakra. This was testified during the war between Indra and Krishna over Parijaat flowers. During that fight, Sudarshan Chakra gulped the VAJRA.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv - You are wrong in Mahabharata era when the was collision between Arjuna's Bramhastra and Ashwatthama's Bramhastra seem eminent Shri Krishna ordered Arjuna to take back his Bramhastra and he did so but Ashwatthama did not know that vidya and it killed baby parikshit and he became twice born dwija in his mothers womb. So in mahabharata era people like arjuna knew how to take back bramhastra and use it efficently.

Comment: He said that probably because Vajrayudha was made out of Rishi Dadhichi's bones, so nothing can mach the sacrifice of the great sage.

Comment: Vajra would be more popular/used as (for) ordnance than Sudarshan(Divine vision) Chakra.

Comment: "Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged" - https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/480/12304 @@srimannarayanakv

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me :-) @YDS

Answer (score 3):

By mentioning the word 'Vajra', does not always relate to Indra's Vajra. 
Just like if one says 'Trishula' then it does not always mean Shiva's Trishula because many other deities also possess Trishula.

The word Vajra also means  'Hardest' weapon . A thing very difficult to crush. 
I think by word Vajra Lord refers to the hardest of all weapons. 
So I feel Lord describes himself as a weapon which is 'the Hardest'.

Why Lord does not mention 'Sudarshan Chakra' here is a good doubt. 
Well I personally think the reason is that it must not be the hardest then.

Answer (score 1):

आयुधानामहं वज्रं Means Those Weapons (आयुध) are used for fighting war. In these, **Indra Vajra is superior** because It is made up of **Bones of Sage Dadhichi** and In this, Maharishi Dadhichi is the fastest of penance.

**Background Story**

When Demon Rakhtabeej terrored all Devas they made refugees of Maharishi Dadhichi they gave own all weapons to Dadhichi ji. He made
water of all weapons and then, he drink that water.Also, he has boon from Lord Shiv that his bones will made up of Vajra.

**Vajra is made up of all weapons of Devata.**

God has called it his own glory.Which is not worthless, meaningless or in vain. His penance will never be worthless because Maharishi Dadhichi died for public welfare after death he  was sumed into Lord Shiva.
See In.

1. **19-20th Shloka of 11th Chapter of 6th Canto of Shreemad Bhagvata Mahapuranam**
2. **Shree Shiv Mahapuranam**

Comment: Not answering the question please. @user17854

Answer (score -3):

Indra is the supreme god in Rig Vedas. Vajra was specifically made as the supreme of all weapons for this lord of gods to use. Indra is the actual Mahendra and Maheswara. Sudarshana and Trishula are just some other weapons made using Vajra material. Maybe later day additions. Like many attributes of Indra went to these two gods namely Vishnu and Shiva, their followers have attributed the strength of Vajra to both these weapons. Vajra is indeed the chief of all weapons and Indra is the chief of all gods ( including the trinity )

Comment: You should cite sources. Please visit [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/3500)