# Was Sri Krishna actually “unable” to repeat the Gita,what’s the Vaishnav/Shaiva stance on this?

Tags: shiva, krishna, bhagavad-gita

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=90RFARD8Rfk&list=PLoKnMdfD1SWLFMIDJojhUTHHIuEQ9esAT&index=14

2:24-2:43

Above is the basis of my question.If this is actually true,then does it mean Sri Krishna and the “Supreme Reality” are distinct?

*As a footnote,what implications does this verse have for Advaita thought?

Comment: You can find the reference you are looking for in this answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/18335

Comment: After the Ashwamedha Arjuna asks Krishna to repeat what he said before the war (Gita). But Krishna says Arjuna should have paid attention when it was said first; he still gives the summary of what was narrated previously. It's repeat of Gita and it's message. So, Krishna had narrated it again. Vishwaroopa as well he showed this to Upamanyu. So, entire Gita is repeated.

Comment: @Kanthri So did the Lord repeat all the 700 verses from the beginning?

Comment: Krishna didn't repeat it in 700 verses but repeated all the key messages once again. Worth noting here:, the messages in Gita is said many times in Bharata-in Vana/Udhyoga parvas, Shanti/Anushasana parvas. Krishna summarised all in 700 shlokas together but you can find every message from Gita all over Bharata.

Comment: So, if the question is Krishna's ability to repeat the message, there is proof that he can.

Comment: @Kanthri Would you please list some references of the messages of the Gita  in the said Parvas?